# ESLint warning; defined but never used for react-native components

Tags: react-native, eslint

It shows defined but never used for imported components; even though the very component is used. How do ignore this eslint warning?

Eg:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
```

....

and added inside render function

```
render(){
<Provider store={appStore}>
 ......
</Provider>
}
```

It show's Provider is defined but not used. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've finally fixed it here is the solution;

first, install the `eslint-plugin-react` and make changes in your .eslintrc.json file.

```
 {
...
"extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended"
    ],
...
}
```

Solution source:
https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/issues/6